# Unable to connect to MongodB deployed on a VM on Google Cloud via Python application using SSHTunnelForwarder

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB instance on Google cloud via local python using SSHTunnelForwarder. I've created the SSH keys and am able to use them to successfully connect to the DB using Putty. However, I'm unable to connect via Python. The error seems to be because of the remote bind address. Code is:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ("36.145.135.175",22),
    ssh_username='mongodb.user',
    ssh_pkey="rsaKey",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
)

    server.start()
    print(server.local_bind_port)

Error:
----> 7     remote_bind_address=('0,0,0,0', 27017)
      8 )
      9 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py in __init__(self, ssh_address_or_host, ssh_config_file, ssh_host_key, ssh_password, ssh_pkey, ssh_private_key_password, ssh_proxy, ssh_proxy_enabled, ssh_username, local_bind_address, local_bind_addresses, logger, mute_exceptions, remote_bind_address, remote_bind_addresses, set_keepalive, threaded, compression, allow_agent, host_pkey_directories, *args, **kwargs)
    902             allow_agent=allow_agent,
    903             host_pkey_directories=host_pkey_directories,
--> 904             logger=self.logger
    905         )
    906 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py in _consolidate_auth(ssh_password, ssh_pkey, ssh_pkey_password, allow_agent, host_pkey_directories, logger)
   1093 
   1094         if not ssh_password and not ssh_loaded_pkeys:
-> 1095             raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
   1096         return (ssh_password, ssh_loaded_pkeys)
   1097 

ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi @shiv-chhabra, maybe you are missing password...?

Comment: using SSH so password isn't required. The keys work via Putty. The error is in my Python code

Comment: you got that right? `ValueError: No password or public key available!`

Comment: @AndyK the code isn't fetching the SSH key from the server. It does so in Putty.It look like that I'm not being able to establish a connection with the remote server

Comment: You must specify the IP address for `remote_bind_address`. The address `0.0.0.0` is a special address used for IP listeners which means listen on all network interfaces. You cannot use that address as a destination as the address does not exist.

Comment: @JohnHanley Where do I find this address? The SSH host is ("36.145.135.175",22). This is the external IP of the VM. What is the remote binding address?

Comment: Look at Example 2: https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/

Comment: @JohnHanley what would the 'remote_bind_address=(PRIVATE_SERVER_IP, 22)' be?

Comment: @JohnHanley As per my understanding the '(REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 443)' is  ("36.145.135.175",22) so what is the remote bind address?

Comment: The address of the system you want the tunnel to forward your connection. The link I sent you has picture and code that show how to do this.